# Chrome hides iframe scrollbar when you display google maps

Tags: css, google-maps, google-chrome, iframe, scrollbar

I want to display a google map in IFrame with scrollbar.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    A website
    <br />
    <iframe src="http://parkall.hu/teszt/parkolok/index.html" 
     style="overflow: scroll; width: 540px; height: 630px;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

It works in the latest firefox (v17), but not in Chrome (v23), strangely enough Chrome displays scrollbars for a moment and hides after that. The scrollbar is still useable if you find out to grab an invisible thing....

Have you ever noticed this? Maybe it can be solved with a CSS but i was unable to find out, the scrolling="yes" attribute is not supported in HTML5. And of course if I change scr to wikipedia.org it displays scroll bar.

Comment: Working fine for me in Chrome v23.

Comment: Working fine for me also...

Comment: Did you try the example code? My guess is that google maps itself disables the scrollbars with javascript. This would mean that your example code works, because your example isn't including google maps.

Comment: @DamienOvereem The URL you see in src="" includes google maps. And it is a working example. http://parkall.hu/teszt/scrollsample.htm

Comment: And iframe in an iframe? .. Well i can imagine that messing things up :) I'm not going to burn my hands on this.

Comment: @DamienOvereem Sorry I don't really understand what you say. I have a website with google maps, and i was asked to include it in an other website as is. There is one iframe in the external site, but my site doesn't contain any...

Comment: @BillyMoat I have tried with a different PC, and worked me too, it should be some timing issue...

Comment: On your page you have an iframe with src http://parkall.hu/teszt/parkolok/index.html. http://parkall.hu/teszt/parkolok/index.html contains an iframe containing google maps. Thats what i mean with an iframe in an iframe.  Iframe within an iframe is a bad idea.(actually iframes are a bad idea period, but you cant do google maps without them..)

Comment: <div id="mapPanel"> contains the map in index.html, so i still see one Iframe, but agree with you that iframe is not the best design ever...

Answer (score 0):

There is a decent chance that google maps tries to disable the scrollbar from its iframe with javascript. In that case you will need some javascript of your own to counter that a few seconds after pageload (by using setTimeout()).

What you need to change in your setTimeout depends on what is happening that hides the scrollbars. Since the example is not complete, I can't determine what happens exactly.

Please put your code in jsfiddle.net and reply with the link so we can check the exact problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uPt5t/  I have changed map code to what I found on maps api documentation. It seems that maps api hides it really, if i added 2s delay before called mapinit js, the scroll bar is visible for 2s and disappears.

Comment: Thats what I figured. And it makes absolute sense tbh. Google maps has its own scrolling functionality. There is no reason to want a scrollbar ontop of that.